# another ways to receive an id without html

Tags: javascript

I'm just trying to get to the lower part of the variable "diemap" and have tried it by  .unfortunately, is not

know one another possibility or somehow how I can integrate this as a var? thanks in advance

ps, the dates of mapname he gets by the client in which the page is bound times later so make you no thoughts.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw1LQ.png

its all written in a `script.js` and yeah that's the reason why I am searching for another way to transmitting the variable.

the code:

```
function GameDetails( servername, serverurl, mapname, maxplayers, steamid, gamemode ) {
    document.getElementById( "s-name" ).innerHTML = servername;
    document.getElementById( "s-mode" ).innerHTML = gamemode;
    document.getElementById( "diemap" ).innerHTML = mapname;
}

function getBackgrounds(weit, callback) {
    $.get("backgrounds/" + weit + "/1.jpg")
        .done(function () {
        callback(weit);
    })
    .fail(function () {
        callback('default');
    });
}

getBackgrounds( "<span id="diemap">unkow</span>" , function (response) 
{
    $('#ergebnis').html(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get the question based on the grammar but your syntax is wrong on this line

`getBackgrounds( "<span id="diemap">unkow</span>" , function (response) {`

You need to either escape the double quotes or use single quotes around `diemap`

`getBackgrounds( "<span id='diemap'>unkow</span>" , function (response) {`

Escaping them:

`getBackgrounds( "<span id=\"diemap\">unkow</span>" , function (response) {`